# gradle fails to compile java classes using kotlin class

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have a gradle 4.1 multiproject containing a "projectA" containing 2 subfolders "api" and "implementation".

The multiproject uses `kotlin` and `java-library` plugins defined in the subprojects section of the main build.gradle.
The implementation project avec a API dependency to `:projectA:api`

In the api folder I have kotlin and java files inside 'src/main/java' and in the implementation project I'm creating a new instance of a kotlin class from the API.

Inside Intellij Idea, I don't have any compilation errors ; but when I compile the whole project using gradle I have an `error: cannot find symbol`. It is as if the `compileJava` doesn't have access to the folder `kotlin-classes`.

Inside the `build/kotlin-classes`, I see my file.class
The class file is on build/classes dir also

**Details of the error :**

> Task :projectA:api:compileKotlin
>   Using kotlin incremental compilation
>
> Task :projectA:implementation:compileJava
>   (...) error: cannot find symbol (the import fails)

**Update 1** : removing java-library solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_known_issues_compat) of the `java-library` plugin: when used in a project with another JVM language (Kotlin, Scala, Groovy etc.) , it does not register the classes of the other language so that the dependent projects get them as they consume the classes.

Fortunately, it has a workaround as well. Adapted to Kotlin, it would look like:

```
configurations {
    apiElements {
        outgoing.variants.getByName('classes').artifact(
            file: compileKotlin.destinationDir,
            type: ArtifactTypeDefinition.JVM_CLASS_DIRECTORY,
            builtBy: compileKotlin)
    }
}
```

<sup>If you use Kapt1, it's `file: compileKotlinAfterJava.destinationDir`, and for Gradle versions lower than 4.0 use `builtBy: copyMainKotlinClasses` instead.</sup>

This issue is also tracked in the Kotlin issue tracker: [KT-18497](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18497), follow that issue to see when it's fixed on the Kotlin Gradle plugin side, so that the above workaround will be no more necessary.